# What does DC=dmd in a makefile do?

Tags: macos, makefile

I am trying to run a makefile on a mac but I am getting an error that says "dmd: command not found".

The makefile has the line 
    DC=dmd

What does this do?

Comment: It sets the `DC` variable to the value `dmd`. You'll need to show us the Makefile (or tell us where it came from) for us to make a guess as to what that's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an assignement, it's difficult to say without more informations. As Google can help you, 'Dmd' is compilator for the D programming language or an old version of [GNU Shepherd](https://www.gnu.org/software/shepherd/) compatible with POSIX system... You have to install these dependence, before trying to make.

Comment: "GNU shepherd version POSIX compatible"? I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.

Comment: Ew sorry, 'an old version of GNU shepherd compatible with POSIX system'.

Comment: Aha! Added a link to clarify.